# Pickling error : Can't pickle <class 'Player.Player'>: it's not the same object as Player.Player

Tags: python, python-import, pickle

Sorry if this question has been asked before, I've seen similar and responses were saying to fiddle with inputs, but I have been trying to adjust for awhile to no success. Here is how my code is written

```
import Player
import API
import pickle
class PlayerList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.NUMPLAYERS = len(API.getGeneral()['elements'])
        self.players = [None]*self.NUMPLAYERS
        for p in range(self.NUMPLAYERS):
            player = API.getPlayer(p+1)
            player_data = API.getPlayerData(p+1)
            self.players[p]=Player.Player(player,player_data)
            left = self.NUMPLAYERS-p
            if left%100==0:
                print(left, " leftover")
    def saveAsPickle(self,fname):
        with open(fname, 'wb') as outp:
                pickle.dump(self, outp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

The Player file is written as

```
from Fixture import Fixture
import API
import Team

class Player:
    def __init__(self,player,player_data):
        self.id = player['id']
        self.first_name = player['first_name']
        self.last_name = player['second_name']
        self.positionType = player['element_type']
        teamID = player['team']
        self.team = Team.Team(API.getTeam(teamID))
        self.influence = player['influence']
        self.creativity = player['creativity']
        self.threat = player['threat']
        self.penalties = player['penalties_order']
        self.freekicks = player['direct_freekicks_order']
        self.corners = player['corners_and_indirect_freekicks_order']
        self.totalGoals = player['goals_scored']
        self.totalAssists = player['assists']
        self.totalCleanSheets = player['clean_sheets']
        self.totalOwnGoals = player['own_goals']
        self.totalPenaltiesMissed = player['penalties_missed']
        self.totalPenaltiesSaved = player['penalties_saved']
        self.totalSaves = player['saves']
        self.totalYellows = player['yellow_cards']
        self.totalReds = player['red_cards']
        self.totalBps = player['bps']
        self.totalBonus = player['bonus']
        self.totalMinutes = player['minutes']
        hist = player_data['history']
        numFixtures = len(hist)
        self.fixtures = [None]*numFixtures
        for f in range(numFixtures):
            fixture = hist[f]
            self.fixtures[f]=Fixture(fixture)
```

When I try to use the saveAsPickle method I always get that error, what am I doing wrong here? I have tried both import Player and then calling Player.Player, as well as importing Player from Player.

Comment: can you put the full error you are receiving?